# Heroku and Restful API Privacy and Security problems

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ssl, heroku, privacy

I have a problem with Heroku and my ReactJS application on the front-end side. I have RESTfull API with Ruby on Rails uploaded on the Heroku server ( to do some testings before I purchase actual hosting), and suddenly from today, i cannot use my API on the Heroku, due Privacy and SSL errors ( I didn't change or update anything on Heroku and the API). I got those errors on the browser : 
[image]

I cannot find any solution online. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [rack cors](https://github.com/cyu/rack-cors) to enable CORS. Add this code to your config/application.rb

```
use Rack::Cors do
  allow do
    origins '*'
    resource '*', headers: :any, methods: :any
  end  
end
```

Comment: I doesn't help me :/

Comment: did you install the gem ?

Comment: Yes, I did. I think the problem is caused by Heroku, and not the app itself.